# Get text from span tag with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to get this element with Python and Selenium.

```
<h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple">
    <span title="Director">Director=</span>
<h2>
```

This is what I tried:

```
try:
    title  = job.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@class="title"]//a').text
except:
    title = job.find_element_by_xpath('.//h2[@class="title"]//a').get_attribute(name="title")
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//h2[@class="title"]//a"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text *`Director`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.jobTitle > span[title]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(@class, 'jobTitle')]/span[@title]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.jobTitle > span[title]"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(@class, 'jobTitle')]/span[@title]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 2):

You are using absolutely wrong locator.
The `h2` element class attribute value is `jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple`, not `title`.
The child element tag name is `span`, not `a`.
Please try this:

```py
title  = job.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[@class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple"]//span').text
```

You will possibly need to add a wait / delay to add before that to let the page loaded before you trying to access that element.

Answer (score 0):

**To get The text From a Page**

```
Des = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="class name of required data"]').text
```

Here only the class name of span tag from where you want to get the text